# C# Coding using strings in order to find a full name

Tags: c#, string, split

I am using Visual studio to create a C# `windows form` that helps me find the suffix,first and last name of the user. I am using `string.split` to find the first space and split from there but it only gives me from the first space onward. if the user input "    Mr.      Donald     duck     " I can not manage to make it work in the situation.

"Mr. -5 spaces- Donald -5spaces- Duck"
the code doesn't read past the first space.
any suggestions?

Comment: THANK YOU everyone, i used a combination of **kaz** and **Avneesh Srivastava**  to solve my problem. if i have any other questions i will be sure to check here,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always use String.Trim() function. (To remove  leading and trailing white-space from string) when you deal with user input as a string.

```
string s = " Mr. Donald duck ";
// Split string on spaces.
// ... This will separate all the words.
string[] words = s.Trim().Split(' ');
//.....check size of array.
if(words.Length ==3)
{
    string suffix=words[0];
    string firstname=words[1];
    string lastname=words[2];
}
```

I am not getting -5 in your question but hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

[Trimming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx) is only going to take care of leading and trailing white-space characters. [Here's what you need](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131448(v=vs.110).aspx) in order to get just the 3 useful parts of the text when you have all those extra spaces between words:

```
string name = "Mr.     Donald     Duck";
string[] split = name.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

The string array will contain 3 items: `Mr.`, `Donald`, and `Duck`. The `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` will take care of repeating white-space when you split the original string.

Without it, you get something like this: `Mr.`, , , , , `Donald`, , , , , `Duck`

Answer (score 0):

Split with remove empty string option, then you will get non empty word array as result. From that you can get name parts.

[Demo](http://rextester.com/SFPMJ91408)

Answer (score 0):

The Syntax for String.Split would be like this:

```
    //             0     1     2
    //            ooo|oooooo|oooo   
    string str = "Mr. Donald Duck";

    string suffix = str.Split(' ')[0];
    string fname = str.Split(' ')[1];
    string lname = str.Split(' ')[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for explanation 
According to MSDN You can easily remove white spaces from both ends of a string by using the String.Trim method. You can read it [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxbw3kwc(v=vs.110).aspx). For more good understanding you can visit [here](https://www.dotnetperls.com/trim)

```
string input = Console.ReadLine();
            // This will remove white spaces from both ends and split on the basis of spaces in string.
string[] tokens = input.Trim().Split(' ');

string title = tokens[0];
string firstname = tokens[1];
string secondname = tokens[2];
```